# How to find all the indexes of dictionaries in a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

I want to find the index of the dictionaries in a list.
For example:
I have a list contains 3 dictionaries:

```
armies = [{'tag': 'red', 'score': 3, 'speed': 'slow'}, 
          {'tag': 'red', 'score': 3, 'speed': 'slow'}, 
          {'tag': 'red', 'score': 3, 'speed': 'slow'}]
```

I want to print out each item in the list and find out the index of the item.
I use codes below:

```
for item in armys:
    index = armys.index(item)
    print(index)
```

Why I always got zero for index?

```
0
0
0
```

Did I miss any thing?

Comment: use `for index, item in enumerate(armies): `

Comment: `index()` returns the index of the first matching element. All your dictionaries are the same, so you always get `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two dictionaries are equal if their keys are the same and they have the same values. For example: `{'b': 2, 'a': 1} == {'a': 1, 'b': 2}` gives `True`. `list.index(needle)` just goes over each element and returns the first `idx` for which `list[idx] == needle`

Comment: Thank you all!!!

Comment: I forget armys.index() can only find the first item in the list if there are have more the same items in the list. Thank you for your notice and advise for enumerate(armies)